# how to skip content block in wordpad

Tags: windows, vb.net, wordpad

I writing a code in vb.net. The codes will create a .rtf (wordpad file format). in that code i'm not only write text but a picture as well. the problem is windows always ask content security everytime i add a picture (fyi, picture already exist in my computer) into that file. 
this is the preview

[image]

i tried to find setting in windows and wordpad, but still got nothing

how can i skip this security warning?

thank you

Comment: Are you trying to open the file after downloading it from the internet?

Comment: no. i'm just add a local picture (file already exist in my computer) file into that .rtf file. any suggestion?

Comment: You usually see warnings like that when you download a ZIP file from the internet, extract it to a folder and then try to open a file from that folder. The folder is considered untrusted because the ZIP file was untrusted. In that case, you need to open the ZIP file properties, check the *Unblock* box and then hit OK to explicitly trust the ZIP file, the folder created by extracting it will also be trusted. Is there any possibility that you could be affected by something like that? It's the only reason I'm aware of for that warning but I don't know everything.

Comment: That's an Alternate Stream attached to files which come from untrusted sources, usually another machine with no local ACL (files downloaded from the (Inter)net). You can use [Streams.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams) to remove Alternate Streams in batch.

Comment: Or use [DeleteFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile) adding the `:alt` suffix to the file name `(DeleteFile("filename.ext:alt");`).

Comment: i think its a miss understanding happened. the picture file that i mean is a very normal jpg file, that i created from paint. i think its about wordpad or windows setting. thank you anyway

Comment: I can confirm this, I have the exact same problem. Just regular rtf with local jpg pasted into them results in blocked content. Can't find how to turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I'm seeing the same issue. RTF created by hand by myself, new text with a few URLs, and pasted images captured by Windows screenshot grabbing app.

Dir /r was showing no alternate stream, but I still got the annoying message box every time I open the file.

Turns out the blocked content were the images, they also won't get copied to the clipboard. Tried grabbing them again, and pasting them to Paint and back to the document, and now WordPad likes them.

Comment: This increases file size as WordPad saves the picture in wmf format, not png. (Actually wmf format is considered secure whereas the png format leads to the security warning even though most probably png files are secure as well)